# How do I display the plane of best fit in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, probability-or-statistics, fitting

I'm trying to display the plane of best fit in the same 3D-box. Currently, I have the following code which spits out a plot of the points in 3D. I want to have a plane of best fit, can Mathematica do this automatically?

```
t1 = {{10.26`, 43.`, 330.`}, {985.69`, 28.`, 120.`}, {1445.56`, 35.`, 
360.`}, {1188.19`, 33.`, 270.`}, {574.51`, 44.`, 220.`}, {568.95`,
 19.`, 170.`}, {471.81`, 20.`, 70.`}, {537.35`, 22.`, 
210.`}, {514.07`, 21.`, 200.`}, {174.09`, 40.`, 300.`}, {1720.81`,
 32.`, 290.`}, {611.48`, 20.`, 70.`}, {251.19`, 24.`, 
150.`}, {97.97`, 38.`, 190.`}, {406.81`, 24.`, 240.`}, {265.4`, 
25.`, 100.`}, {1323.29`, 35.`, 250.`}, {196.65`, 36.`, 
210.`}, {1326.6`, 27.`, 280.`}, {1380.69`, 33.`, 230.`}};

ListPointPlot3D[t1]
```

Comment: Yeah every ones got the sheet fit, the plane is pretty rare to find

Comment: Define `fit = Fit[t1, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]`, then use `Plot3D`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to get the plane of best fit: subtract the centroid of the data, and then plot the plane generated by the first two left singular vectors of the singular value decomposition of the resulting data:

```
Y = # - Mean /@ # &[t1\[Transpose]]
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[Y];
Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, U[[;; , 1]], U[[;; , 2]]}], 
  Point /@ (Y\[Transpose])}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

which produces

[image]

The RMS error is the third singular value:

```
S[[3, 3]]
```

which produces

```
25.8873
```

Comment: +1, I think there may be a syntax error as `Y` is not defined. Copy and paste does not run. Should it be: `{U, S, V} = 
  SingularValueDecomposition[Y = # - Mean /@ # &[t1\[Transpose]]];
Graphics3D[{InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, U[[;; , 1]], U[[;; , 2]]}], 
  Point /@ (Y\[Transpose])}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]` or alternatively plotting original points by translating plane.

Comment: @ubpdqn: Dang, you're right, sorry 'bout that! Fixing it.

Comment: Why don't you plot the plane against the actual data `t1`?

Answer (score 8):

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[t1, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Bottom],
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate@Fit[t1, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]
  , {x, Min[t1[[All, 1]]], Max[t1[[All, 1]]]}
  , {y, Min[t1[[All, 2]]], Max[t1[[All, 2]]]}
  ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's very beautiful graph, mathematica is very powerful thank you for your help, this problem is solved :)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the plane of best fit is also the sum of least squares?

Comment: This particular fit minimizes sums of squares of vertical discrepancies. For total least squares (sums of squares of shortest rather than vertical distances to plane), one would have to do this a bit differently.

Comment: really?? uh oh, so is there a more effective function than fit??

Comment: Isn't that minimum the same for a linear function (plane) ?

Comment: @rhermans: Not quite, the plane of best fit is different from the plane of best vertical fit, although for point clouds which nearly outline a horizontal plane the difference will be fairly small. One way to get the true plane of best fit (and the associated RMS error) is to use principal value decomposition of the data (see my answer for details).

Comment: This is a complicated answer, im going to have to learn a fair bit more of the mathematica API and the least squares method, but thanks, I will now reverse engineer your answer, really appreciate the help

Comment: Hey can you recomend reading to understand all this?

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [`ResourceFunction["PlaneOfBestFit"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlaneOfBestFit) to find the best plane for a set of points.  Using the example from the OP,

```
In[40]:= ResourceFunction["PlaneOfBestFit"]@t1

Out[40]= InfinitePlane[{{702.569, 29.95, 213.}, {703.567, 29.9501, 
   213.055}, {702.623, 29.8805, 212.004}}]
```

I recently wanted this functionality and my searches led me to DumpsterDoofus's answer as well as this [math forum post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180313022256/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63765.html).  I made a standalone function to get the plane from a set of points, and [Daniel Lichblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) extended it to work with n-dimensional points.

The reason I wanted to do this was to visualize the plane of a ring in a molecule, to visualize sterochemistry:

```
m = Molecule["adenosine"];
aliphaticRing = 
  Flatten@Values@
    FindMoleculeSubstructure[m, 
     ResourceFunction["MoleculeRingPattern"][{"O", _, _, _, _}]];
points = QuantityMagnitude@m["AtomCoordinates"][[aliphaticRing]];
plane = ResourceFunction["PlaneOfBestFit"][points];
Show[MoleculePlot3D[m], Graphics3D@{Red, Opacity[.7], plane}]
```

The 3D plane helps to see how the adenine ring is on the opposite side of the ribose ring from the hydroxyl groups.
[image]

Comment: You might like this OG reference: [Pearson 1901](http://pca.narod.ru/pearson1901.pdf)

Comment: Very nice - I can add a link to that on the reference page.

Comment: @Chris and Jason, [this](https://doi.org/10.1080/14786440109462720) would be the official link. ;) Jason, I'll also e-mail you later about this.